# Micronaut Get raw HttpRequest

Tags: micronaut, micronaut-rest

My app gets deployed to customer sites.
Some customers have proxies that perform authentication of users then forward a particular HTTP cookie/header.
These can be of custom format.
I want to be able to provide one micronaut URL e.g. /customAuth
That a customer can provide an override for
Allowing them to forward the request from their proxy and handle it themselves.

Unfortunately this is proving very hard in micronaut as:

1. It inists I specify @Post/@Get or what the HTTP method should be.
2. It parses the headers/body before forwarding.

What I really need is:

`@All(/customAuth) HttpResponse customAuth(String fullRawHttpRequestWithHeaders) {`

I've seen this question on raaw body ([Get raw HttpRequest body in Micronaut](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58738475/get-raw-httprequest-body-in-micronaut)). I share their problem that I don't even know if there will be a body.

I've seen this question on getting headers:
[How to get full list of request headers in Micronaut](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62436891/how-to-get-full-list-of-request-headers-in-micronaut)

It seems micronaut really just does NOT want to give raw access which is what some people really need, e.g. in my case.

Is this the case?

Comment: Are you asking how to map all requests to a certain URI to a particular controller method and not having to specify which http methods are applicable, or are you asking how to get a reference to the HTTP request, or are you asking something else?

Comment: "Are you asking how to map all requests to a certain URI to a particular controller method and not having to specify which http methods are applicable,"
Yes.
That plus how to get the whole HTTP request as a string.

Comment: I don't think we have support for doing exactly that.  You could address some of it by implementing an HTTP filter.

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to recreate the raaw requests as best as possible .e.g

```
    StringBuilder ms = new StringBuilder();
    // add cookies
    Map<String, Cookie> m = req.getCookies().asMap();
    m.forEach((t, u) -> ms.append(t + ":" + u.getValue()));
        
    // add headers
    req.getHeaders().asMap().entrySet().
    .. add body
```

This seems a huge waste of effort, inefficient and likely to go wrong.

Comment: "One solution would be to recreate the raaw requests as best as possible" - The code in this answer does not look like it is recreating any request.